# Retrieving TriangleCount

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm trying to retrieve the amount of triangles from a graph using graphX.
As I'm new to both Scala and graphX, I'm currently quite stuck.

I'm creating a graph from an edgefile:

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

This should be 1 triangle.

Next I'm using the build in function val `countTriangles = graph.triangleCount`.

I've however so far been unable to extract the actual trianglecount from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`triangleCount` counts number of triangles per vertex and returns `Graph[Int,Int]`, so you have to extract vertices:

```
scala>  graph.triangleCount().vertices.collect()
res0: Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Int)] = Array((1,1), (3,1), (2,1))
```

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. So getting the total amount of triangles would be summing these values and dividing by three! Thanks.

Comment: how do you sum these values? (the number of triangles per vertex)